# Cannot run Android Chromecast examples

Tags: java, android, chromecast, eclipse-adt

I am attempting to run the "democastplayer" example (same behavior with tic tac toe) in android and it seems to fail when I run it on my phone.  The error is pretty clear but I have no idea what is causing it.  My project is compiling just fine but when it runs I get the class not found error.  I have included the appcompat_v7, android-support-v7-mediarouter, and google-play-services-lib projects in eclipse using the below method.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

FWIW - I am compiling with build 21, doing my development on a 64 bit ubuntu, and my hello world examples run just fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076): Process: com.google.android.gms.cast.samples.democastplayer, PID: 22076
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityManagerCompat;
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter.<init>(MediaRouter.java:1528)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.getInstance(MediaRouter.java:220)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at com.google.android.gms.cast.samples.democastplayer.BaseCastPlayerActivity.onCreate(BaseCastPlayerActivity.java:182)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at com.google.android.gms.cast.samples.democastplayer.SdkCastPlayerActivity.onCreate(SdkCastPlayerActivity.java:51)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.ActivityManagerCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms.cast.samples.democastplayer-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    ... 17 more
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.app.ActivityManagerCompat
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):        ... 18 more
10-19 06:59:41.702: E/AndroidRuntime(22076):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: do you have 'support/v4' lib in the project?

Comment: Robert, Thank you very much.

I think that I do (a bit new at this) but I have included appcompat_v7 as my Android Library and that has two jars in it (android-support-v4.jar, android-support-v7-appcompat.jar).  I would ASSume that this means it is in my path.

Eclipse is compiling just fine it just pukes when i run it.  I ASSume this means it has it in its path in eclipse but once I leave eclipse it loses it.

Comment: and are you running proguard?  ie which version build ( debug , release) . if release then make sure to bypass the v4 packages in proguard config file

Comment: Thanks again.

I am not running proguard.  It appears to be commented out in my project.properties.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm seeing the same exact issue. FWIW both android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar are checked in the Order and Export tab in the Java Build Path in the android-support-v7-appcompat library project.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm. go to the 'project.props' file for the parent lib of the v4/support jar.

review ['referencing a lib project'](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html)

This parenet lib should be mention as lib in your main project.pros and try modify the child to contain the v4/support ( sample sort of below

```
target=android-19
android.library=true
android.library.reference.1=../../../../usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
android.library.reference.2=../../../../usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/mediarouter
android.library.reference.3=../../../../usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thank you very much.  I decided to take a day and setup my environment using Fedora instead. I wanted to stop using Ubuntu and in the back of my mind I was hoping that there was something wrong with my Ubuntu install.  Alas - not the case up and running on Fedora and I have the exact same problem.  

In this case my parent project is my DemoCastPlayer project.  I checked the project.props and they are correct (like yours).  The project compiles just fine in eclipse (meaning it can resolve all dependencies) but once I deploy to my phone then I get the above errror.

Answer (score 0):

there are two different v4.jar, the v4.jar in appcompat_v7 has not contain the ActivityManagerCompat class,so should replace the v4.jar from sdk\extras\android\support\v4 to appcompat_v7 lib.

Comment: What are you basing that on?? Those two jars are identical (run checksum if you have any doubts)

Comment: THank you very much.  Unfortunately I have determined that both are the same.  I even switched the classpath to use the other one with the exact same result.